# Unexpected behaviours for multiple programmatic click events

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe UI using PyQt5. Three modes are provided

1. Human vs. Human
2. Human vs. AI
3. AI vs. AI game

All modes work very fine except that in mode 3 (Two AIs play against each other), the UI will start loading and display the final result, instead of refreshing the intermediate steps of each turn until the game start, which I expected and preferred. How can I achieve it? Thank you!

---

Below is my code:

```
class TicTacToeUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    icons = ['icons/x-mark.png', 'icons/hollow-circle.png']

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("TicTacToe")
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D7CCC8;')
        # Players
        self._players_selector = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self._players = list()
        for p in range(2):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Player {:}'.format(p))
            selectbox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            selectbox.setFixedHeight(24)
            selectbox.addItems(list(PLAYERS.keys()))
            self._players_selector.addWidget(label, 0, p)
            self._players_selector.addWidget(selectbox, 1, p)
            self._players.append(selectbox)
        self._grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self._gameboard_buttons = dict()
        for i in range(self.m):
            for j in range(self.n):
                btn = self.create_gameboard_button(row=i, col=j)
                self._grid.addWidget(btn, i, j)
                self._gameboard_buttons.update({(i, j): btn})
        self._message_box = QtWidgets.QLabel('', parent=self)
        self._restart_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', parent=self)
        self._restart_button.setFixedHeight(32)
        self._restart_button.clicked.connect(self.restart)
        # Layout
        self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._layout.addLayout(self._players_selector)
        self._layout.addLayout(self._grid)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._message_box)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._restart_button)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)
        # The game
        self._game = TicTacToe()
        self._started = False

    def create_gameboard_button(self, row, col):
        btn = TicTacToeUIButton('', parent=self, style_sheet='background-color: #D7CCC8;')
        btn.setFixedSize(64, 64)
        btn.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.click, row, col))
        return btn

    def click(self, row, col):
        if not self._started:
            pass
        elif self._game.is_ended:
            pass
        else:
            btn = self._gameboard_buttons.get((row, col))
            if btn is not None:
                if btn.is_occupied:
                    msg = 'It is occupied. Please select another one.'
                    self._message_box.setText(msg)
                else:
                    player = self._game.turn_player
                    # Icon appearance
                    for _, b in self._gameboard_buttons.items():
                        b.remove_border()
                    btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.icons[player]))
                    btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(48, 48))
                    btn.add_border('border: 1px solid #FF0000;')
                    btn.occupied_player = player
                    # Check result
                    self._game.move(row=row, col=col, player=player)
                    if self._game.winner is not None:
                        if self._game.winner == -1:
                            msg = 'Draw. What a game!'
                        else:
                            msg = 'Player {:} won. Congratulations!'
                            msg = msg.format(self._game.winner)
                    else:
                        msg = ''
                    self._message_box.setText(msg)
            # Next turn
            if self._game.is_ended:
                pass
            else:
                self._game.players[self._game.turn_player].decide_ui(self)

    def reset(self):
        self._started = True
        self._game.reset()
        self._game.player0 = PLAYERS.get(self._players[0].currentText())
        self._game.player1 = PLAYERS.get(self._players[1].currentText())
        self._restart_button.setText('Restart')
        self._message_box.setText('')
        for _, btn in self._gameboard_buttons.items():
            btn.reset()
        if self._game.player0.is_ai:
            self._game._player0.decide_ui(self)

    def restart(self):
        self.reset()
```

---

Some notes:

- The game will start right after 'Start'/'Restart' button is clicked, the players, either a Human or an AI will click gameboard button based on their judgment/algorithm.
- `Human().decide_ui(self)` does nothing, while 
  `SomeAI().decide_ui(self)` will click the gameboard buttons based on some algorithms.
- `TicTacToe()` is an object storing the gameboard matrix and the winning criteria.

---

If you are interested in playing the game, you can download whole set of code [here](https://github.com/kitman0804/BoardGame).

Comment: you likely need to slow down the speed at which your AI is finishing the game. You can experiment with the `QTimer` class.

Comment: @Crispin Some of my AI may take 1-2 seconds each turn, but the final result will be shown up directly after a few second of loading. The intermediate ones can't be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded the full app to better understand the whole process.

So, when running, the AI is keeping the main process busy and Qt events are never processed and nothing is drawn on the UI.

The easiest solution is to call [`QApplication.processEvents()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) every turn, like this:

```
def click(self, row, col):
    # "click" code

    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()

    # Next turn
    if self._game.is_ended:
        pass
    else:
        self._game.players[self._game.turn_player].decide_ui(self)
```

This will process all the pending events, and moves will be displayed one at the time.